# Update cell value if no match found

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to format data in one of two sheets in the same workbook and then compare four columns in each of the sheets with each other.

If there is a match between the combination of the four columns then populate one of two strings in the blank column at the end of the range in the Oracle sheet.

If any of the cells in the column are blank after the comparison then it should say person not found.

The problem is it is populating all the cells with person not found and I've done a comparison via a count if and the data is correct and there are matches to be made.

```vb
Sub CompareValues()
    
    Dim bank As Worksheet
    
    Dim Oracle As Worksheet
    
    Dim cell As Range
    
    Dim i As Long, J As Long

    Dim OracleArr As Variant, bankArr As Variant
    
    Dim match As Boolean
    
    Dim Oraclerng As Range
    Dim bankRng As Range
    
    Set Oracle = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Oracle Fusion File")
    Set bank = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Bank File")
    
    Set Oraclerng = Oracle.Range("A2", Oracle.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 10))
    Set bankRng = bank.Range("A2", bank.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 11))
    
    OracleArr = Oraclerng.Value2
    bankArr = bankRng.Value2
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(OracleArr)
        match = False
        For J = 1 To UBound(bankArr)
            If OracleArr(i, 1) = bankArr(J, 8) And OracleArr(i, 6) = bankArr(J, 4) And OracleArr(i, 7) = bankArr(J, 5) And OracleArr(i, 8) = bankArr(J, 8) Then
                  
                    If match Then
                        OracleArr(i, 10) = "Complete match"
                    Else
                        OracleArr(i, 10) = "Investigation Required"
                    End If
                End If
         Next J
    Next i
        
    For i = 1 To UBound(OracleArr)
        If OracleArr(i, 10) = "" Then
            OracleArr(i, 10) = "Person not found"
        End If
    Next i
    
    Oraclerng.Value = OracleArr
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You compare `OracleArr(i, 1)` AND `OracleArr(i, 8)` both to `bankArr(J, 8)` in your `IF` conditions. Is that on purpose?

Comment: Furthermore you never set `match` in your loop, but you always test for `match` to determine which value to write. I suspect it never actually tests `match` though because your `IF` conditions above that always fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to say exactly what is wrong here, but based on my comments above, I think the following should get you closer. Your `if match Then...` test is superfluous as `match` is never set. Instead::

```
Sub CompareValues()

Dim bank As Worksheet

Dim Oracle As Worksheet

Dim cell As Range

Dim i As Long, J As Long

Dim OracleArr As Variant, bankArr As Variant

Dim match As Boolean

Dim Oraclerng As Range
Dim bankRng As Range

Set Oracle = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Oracle Fusion File")
Set bank = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Bank File")

Set Oraclerng = Oracle.Range("A2", Oracle.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 10))
Set bankRng = bank.Range("A2", bank.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 11))

OracleArr = Oraclerng.Value2
bankArr = bankRng.Value2

'loop through Oracle Range
For i = 1 To UBound(OracleArr)

    'set match to false for tihs iteration of i
    match = False

    'loop through bank range
    For J = 1 To UBound(bankArr)

        'Look for a match, if it's found, set match=true and exit the J loop since we found a hit already and any further searching would be a waste.
        If OracleArr(i, 1) = bankArr(J, 8) And OracleArr(i, 6) = bankArr(J, 4) And OracleArr(i, 7) = bankArr(J, 5) And OracleArr(i, 8) = bankArr(J, 8) Then 
            match = true
            exit for
         End If
     Next J

     'while iterating through the bank range (j) did we find a match?
     If match Then                   
         OracleArr(i, 10) = "Complete match"
     Else
         OracleArr(i, 10) = "Investigation Required"
     End If


Next i

'This is probably never going to hit because either match = true or match = false when iterating through `i` (oracle range) the first time. We would have either written `Complete Match` OR `Investigation Required` for every row already. You'll have to refine your logic here or above to get whatever this is supposed to be.
For i = 1 To UBound(OracleArr)
    If OracleArr(i, 10) = "" Then
        OracleArr(i, 10) = "Person not found"
    End If
Next i

Oraclerng.Value = OracleArr

End Sub
```

We loop through `j` and try to find a match. If one is found we set `match` to `true` and we END the `j` loop. Then we see if we have a `match=true` and if so we populate the `oraclearr(i,10)` appropriately.

I still think there may be an issue with your `IF` condition of `OracleArr(i, 1) = bankArr(J, 8) And OracleArr(i, 6) = bankArr(J, 4) And OracleArr(i, 7) = bankArr(J, 5) And OracleArr(i, 8) = bankArr(J, 8)` where `bankArr(j, 8)` is tested twice, but perhaps that is meant to be.

Comment: Hi Jnevill, I've made some amendments to the code as per your recomendation and you were correct. I made a few errors in the if statement and once I also changed around the placement of a few of the lines of code it's now working better than it did before. Thank you again for your help especially with how quick you were in replying.